# How to use Tweepy pagination with Twitter API v2?

Tags: tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to use the Paginator() method so that I can gather more than 100 tweets.

The following is my code:

```
query = '("illegal alien") place_country:US -is:retweet' 

start_time = '2010-04-06T00:00:00Z'
end_time = '2022-12-02T00:00:00Z' 
tweets = tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at', 'geo'], 
                                
                                  place_fields = ['place_type','geo'], expansions='geo.place_id',
                                  start_time=start_time,
                                  end_time=end_time, max_results=100)).flatten(limit=200)

for tweet in tweets:
    print(f"Tweet ID: {tweet.id}\nText: {tweet.text},\nCreated at: {tweet.created_at}\n\n")
```

For some reason, this returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__name__'. Did you mean: '__ne__'?
```

I believe that my Paginator call is not structured correctly, and I am wondering how to properly make the statement.

Answer (score 0):

In the [`Tweepy Docs`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html?highlight=search_recent_tweets#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets) for the `search_recent_tweets` method, the parameters are inside the method signature, whilst the [`Tweepy Docs for Pagination`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html?highlight=search_recent_tweets#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets) has the parameters for `search_recent_tweets` outside the signature and is converted in parameters for the Paingator method.

Here's an example for better clarity:

```
start_time = '2021-04-06T00:00:00Z'
end_time = '2022-12-02T00:00:00Z'

tweets = tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets,
                              query='illegal alien',
                              tweet_fields=[
                                  'context_annotations', 'created_at', 'geo'],
                              place_fields=['place_type', 'geo'],
                              expansions='geo.place_id',
                              start_time=start_time,
                              end_time=end_time, max_results=100)

    print({tweets})
```

This doesn't give any errors and prints a paginator object.